# R - loop iteratively through lists and create a dataframe

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a long list of lists (> 100k) and need to iteratively loop through each list and extract the "id" - which i can do easily by constructing `lapply` in a for loop.

Here is an example of the lists:

```
l1 <- list(id="002e2b45555652749339ab9c34359fb6", key="2", value="xx")
l2 <- list(id="002e2b433226527493jsab9c34353fb6", key="4", value="zz")
l3 <- list(list1, list2)
```

I do the looping with:

```
for(i in 1:20) {
  lapply(l3$id[[i]][1], function (x) print(x))
}
```

Basically printing all the elements of each list of the id - which is nice.
I ultimately want to construct a matrix / dataframe with all the "ids" in rows. What bugs me is, the print in my loop works well, printing out all ids from all the lists - although I cannot bind my rows to a dataframe or a matrix etc. i was trying out something like - ain't doing what i want (although not getting an error etc.)

```
for(i in 1:20) {
  lapply(l3$id[[i]][1], function (x) rbind(x))
}
```

SO the desired output shall be (preferrably as a dataframe).

```
[1] "002e2b45555652749339ab9c3400cc52"
[1] "002e2b45555652749339ab9c34040525"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using base R:

```
s=aggregate(.~ind,stack(setNames(l3,1:length(l3))),identity)
  ind                         values.1 values.2 values.3
1   1 002e2b45555652749339ab9c34359fb6        2       xx
2   2 002e2b433226527493jsab9c34353fb6        4       zz
```

if you just need the id's

```
s$values[,1]
[1] "002e2b45555652749339ab9c34359fb6" "002e2b433226527493jsab9c34353fb6"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a vector of the IDs you can do

```
sapply(l3, "[[", "id")
```

or using tidyverse functions

```
purrr::map_chr(l3, "id")
```

No need for loops for stuff like this in R.

Comment: awesome ! thank you - hadn't had purrr on my radar though